# DataTables turn off buttons on table

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using datatables from datatables.net in my website.  I want to turn off `buttons` for users depending on access.  I thought simply changing `buttons: false` would do the trick but the default buttons are still showing up.

```
$('#member-data-table').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    select: true,
    buttons: false,
    scrolly:400,
    order: [1,'asc'],
    dom       : 'Bfrtip'

});
```

The docs show a setting for `buttons: true`, which is also the default setting if none is provided, logically making it `false` would turn them off but its not working.

Comment: Does this help ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968659/remove-custom-button-from-datatable

Comment: I found this feature in the API.  It works.  The buttons still show but they are disabled, be nice if there was as simple of a way to not even show them.  https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons().disable()

Comment: If you can get the id and the class name of the button you could remove the button class like this $( "Id" ).removeClass( "myClass" );

Comment: Can you use `dom: 'frtip'` instead of `dom: 'Bfrtip'`? This can only be set when the table is initialized, so you would need some conditional logic around it: `var showButtons = 'frtip';` and then `dom: showButtons,`. It would not be dynamic - if a user's access permissions changed mid-session, the effects would probably not be seen until the user left the page and returned.